# Laravel Join not working as expected with DB::Raw

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So the error I am getting is `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'team_members' in field list`

So it seems the join in not actually happening. Does anyone see the problem in the code?

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw('
                Select
                  team_members.name As teamMemberName,
                  Sum(TimestampDiff(minute, production_hours.time_start,
                  production_hours.time_stop)) / 60 As hoursWorked,
                  production_activities.name As groupName,
                  production_hours.team_member_id,
                  production_hours.production_activities_id,
                  production_hours.hourly_rate
                  '))
              ->join('production_days', 'production_hours.production_day_id', '=', 'production_days.id')
              ->join('production_activities', 'production_hours.production_activities_id', '=', 'production_activities_id')
              ->where('DATE(production_day.begin)', '>', $beginDate)
              ->where('DATE(production_day.begin)', '<', $endDate)
              ->groupBy('team_members.name')
              ->groupBy('production_activities.name')
              ->get();
```

EDIT:

Mark Baker pointed out I never specified the table. The correct query(with a couple other bugs fixed):

```
$data = DB::table('production_days')->select(DB::raw('
                  team_members.name As teamMemberName,
                  Sum(TimestampDiff(minute, production_hours.time_start,
                  production_hours.time_stop)) / 60 As hoursWorked,
                  production_activities.name As groupName,
                  production_hours.team_member_id,
                  production_hours.production_activities_id,
                  production_hours.hourly_rate
                  '))
              ->join('production_hours', 'production_hours.production_day_id', '=', 'production_days.id')
              ->join('production_activities', 'production_hours.production_activities_id', '=', 'production_activities_id')
              ->join('team_members', 'production_hours.team_member_id', '=', 'team_members.id')
              ->where(DB::raw('DATE(`production_days`.`begin`)'), '>', $beginDate)
              ->where(DB::raw('DATE(`production_days`.`begin`)'), '<', $endDate)
              ->groupBy('team_members.name')
              ->groupBy('production_activities.name')
              ->get();
```

Comment: So what table are you querying against? You're not specifying in your query. You're simply doing a generic select against nothing

Comment: @MarkBaker Yup, I'm stupid

Comment: Yeah, there's difference between `DB::select()` and `DB::table()->select()` - first is, like @MarkBaker pointed out, a method called on the `Connection` object, which simply runs the query, latter is `Query\Builder` object method, that can be chained the way you needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Best Example use it  with all possible example**

e.g.

```
    $issueitems = \DB::table('products_items')->where("products_items.deleted", "0");
    $data=$issueitems->select(array(
                "itemcategories.name as itemcategoryname",
                "itemsubcategories.name as itemsubcategoryname",
                "items.name as itemsname",
                "items.id as item_id",
                "products_items.stock as stock",
                "measureds.name as measureds",
                \DB::raw("COALESCE(issue_stock.price,0) as price"),
                \DB::raw("COALESCE(issue_stock.iquantity,0) as issuequantity")))
            ->join("products", function($join) {
                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'products_items.product_id')
                ->on("products.deleted", "=", "products_items.deleted");
            })
            ->join("items", "items.id", "=", "products_items.item_id")
            ->join("itemcategories", "itemcategories.id", "=", "items.item_category_id")
            ->join("itemsubcategories", "itemsubcategories.id", "=", "items.item_subcategory_id")
            ->join("measureds", "measureds.id", "=", "items.measured_id")
            ->leftjoin(
                    \DB::raw('(SELECT 
                            productissues.product_id,itemstocks.item_id,sum(productissue_items.quantity) as iquantity
                            ,sum(itemstocks.price * (COALESCE(productissue_items.quantity,0))) as price
                            FROM 
                            productissues
                                INNER JOIN productissue_items ON productissues.id = productissue_items.productissues_id
                                INNER JOIN itemstocks ON itemstocks.id = productissue_items.itemstock_id
                                WHERE itemstocks.deleted = "0" AND productissue_items.deleted = "0"
                                group by productissues.product_id,itemstocks.item_id
                            ) issue_stock'), function($join) {
                $join->on("issue_stock.product_id", "=", "products_items.product_id")
                ->on("issue_stock.item_id", "=", "products_items.item_id");
            })->get();
```